Why does my tankless water heater require almost a minute to provide hot water?
I moved into a new construction home 5 years ago with a tankless water heater. Since day one the hot water has been issue. Initially the sink faucets weren’t producing enough flow rate to even kick on the hot water, so the plumber pull out all the low flow valves. This didn’t work in the kitchen so we needed a new faucet. Although fixed, it takes 45 seconds to get hot water to the kitchen and more than 60 seconds to get hot water to any bathroom sink. It’s so frustrating and honestly a bit embarrassing when guests are trying to wash hands. Any ideas?!

Is there room to install a tank-type water heater? Also, is this some megasprawl McMansion with bathrooms scattered hither and yon throughout the house?

do hot and cold taps give the same water flow?  You are right that this isn't normal.

It sounds like this is a matter of the taps being too far from the hot water source.  You can ask a plumber about installing a hot water circulation loop, but it may be about impossible , may be not.   Perhaps look into point of use tankless water heaters for the sinks that are at issue.

@ThreePhaseEel no, it’s not a huge house. It’s 2350 sq ft, kitchen and 2.5 baths. The hot water heater was placed in back corner of basement. Kitchen sink is on first floor, along the same wall but opposite corner. Two bathrooms are in the center of house on first and second floor, third bathroom is second floor almost directly above the hot water heater.

@TigerGuy could it be an issue with the tank itself, maybe not sized right for the house? I have a Rinnai RL75ip.

RL75ip - That's propane. Which is better than electric but, unlike utility natural gas, raises the question of how well your propane tank works, especially when it is just starting. This heater will run at anywhere from 10k to a whopping 180k Btu/h depending on how much water you are using and the temperature rise (which depends on the incoming that you can't control and the outgoing which you can control).

Could try flushing/descaling the tankless heater, also check if your line has a filter in it that needs replacing.  Also check if the water heater has its own filter that could use cleaning.

If the delayed or not-responding tankless water heater turn-on problem has been solved, and the heater now turns on reasonably right away when any hot water is turned on anywhere, then your delay in getting hot water is typical of hot water systems, tankless or tanked, throughout the ages.
Hot water cools down, and it cools down faster in uninsulated situations, such as in a pipe between the heater and the faucet. And the cold water has to be expelled from the pipe to get the fresh hot water to the faucet, thus the delay in feeling the hot water. Size of the water pipe matters, too: a narrow-diameter pipe will expel its cold water faster than a wider-diameter pipe. If the builder's plumber ran 3/4" pipe to the faucets instead of 1/2", this could be a contribution to the delay.
Here are some solutions and attendant problems:

Have insulation put around the hot water pipes throughout the house. This may help the water stay hotter longer, but not so long that it may still be hot right away in the morning after you turned the faucet off last night. Also, there will be ripping open of walls to access pipes and the subsequent wall repairs.

Re-plumb the hot water plumbing to use a "home run" arrangement, where a manifold, a large pipe with several small pipes branching from it, sits close to the water heater, and each faucet has a separate pipe running back to the manifold. Make the separate pipes to each of the faucets small diameter, 3/8" or even 1/4" diameter, and the narrow pipes will flush out the old cold water quicker, making the delay for hot water shorter. Opening and repairing walls may be required. (This idea provided by DIY.SE guru ThreePhaseEel.)

Have hot water loops installed, which will force hot water around the pipes all the time. Your heater will have to stay running most of the time, especially since it's a tankless (tanks might not have to run all the time due to the tank's insulation, but they will have to run more often than a standard non-looped water system). There will be an electric pump, too. Get ready for higher energy bills with this setup. Insulating the pipes and ripping up & repairing the walls are also required, unless you have even more money for energy bills, and don't care about the environment having all that energy and heat wasted.

Install point-of-use small water heaters at all the embarrassing locations where hot water should be there right away. 2 or 3 gallon under-sink water heaters will carry pretty decent amounts of hand-washing water as long as the water is not wasted. There may also be tankless point-of-use heaters, too, that could feed a shower or the kitchen sink for dish washing. Feed the point-of-use heaters from the cold water, not the hot water, at least for bathroom sinks, and the kitchen sink if you only run hot water there for a few seconds: this will save the energy use running the tankless to heat up water that won't make it to the faucet before the hand washing is finished. You could feed high use locations like kitchen sink (if you hand-wash dishes) and showers from the tankless hot water, and the point-of-use could keep things warmish until the tankless' hot water shows up. You may have to run more electric circuits to the point-of-use heaters. Electric energy use should be rather low compared to a hot water loop. You can also put back the low-flow faucets and save water too.


I think a home run manifold or point-of-use heaters would be the way to go.

There's also the use of a manifold/homerun system with downsized tubing (3/8 or even 1/4) and short runs to minimize the amount of water resident in the piping...

@ThreePhaseEel Interesting thought! Is this concept of a manifold and downsized pipes a possible cause of the slow hot water, or a solution to get faster hot water? And is 1/4" pipe used for feeding faucets and showers?

It's a solution to the slow hot water, and yes, the 1/4" (or more commonly 3/8") is used for feeding faucets & showers

Tanked may have slightly less delay since they also preheat the pipe directly coming out?... :)

@ThreePhaseEel The home run manifold idea is added, thanks!

@rogerdpack that's a good possibility. I wonder how long the heat from the tank could keep the water in the pipe warm, especially if the pipe is insulated.

This answer describes recirculation as operating all the time.  That's a possible configuration, but not the most efficient way.
It is quite possible to set up the recirculation so that it runs when a button is pushed.  You would use this as follows:

Enter the bathroom and push the button.
Use the toilet.
Wash hands.

That way the water is always hot when you wash your hands but is not kept hot between uses.  This maintains the "only when needed" advantage of the tankless while giving you hot water quickly when you actually need it.
Similarly, it is possible to add a motion sensor to the bathroom that recirculates the water whenever someone enters.  No need to remember to push the button (which may remain useful in other locations where entry does not imply that hot water is needed, e.g. a kitchen).
I believe it's also possible to set up the recirculation such that it runs only when the hot water is on.  That might not seem like it would help, but if you have a 3/4" pipe (the old standard size) for most of the travel with a 1/2" fixture (the current standard), then recirculating will cause it to heat a bit more than twice as fast.  E.g. 27 seconds rather than 60.
As a side note, if possible, I would encourage you to run new pipe rather than reusing the cold water pipe to recirculate the water back to the heater.  That way your cold water will stay cold rather than lukewarm.

I've sometimes wondered if you could do the on-demand recirculation off a second contact on an occupancy sensor? pretty rare to be doing something in the bathroom and not want hot water for it now, no?

What is this button configuration you describe? :) I have seen some recirculation pumps that run periodically on a timer...

@rogerdpack  Navien HotButton.  Note that that is specific to Navien.  Presumably other manufacturers have similar options.  ThreePhaseEel, makes sense to me.

@ThreePhaseEel Act D'MAND Kontrols can operate as you describe (motion sensor) or as I describe (manual button).  That's a third party recirculation pump that could presumably work with a variety of water heater brands.  No endorsement intended (product nor retailer), use at your own risk.

@ThreePhaseEel If you're just washing your hands properly, cold water is biologically identical. Washing with warm water is purely a comfort thing.

Remember how tanked heaters had quite a delay?  That was because there is some distance between the water heater and the faucet, and that's run with a pipe.  That pipe is full of water, and the water has cooled down because it's in a pipe, not a heater.
So when you open the valve, that volume of cold water (in the pipe) must be pushed out before hot water can arrive.
OK so swap that tank for a tankless.  What has changed?  Nothing!  There's still a pipe and it's still full of cold water, and you still must wait while it gets pushed out and hot water gets delivered.
Some people expect tankless to be instant hot water. But that doesn't really make sense with a centrally located tankless in about the same location as a tanked heater.  If it's farther away, that's worse.

Now, there is a potential for a tankless system to be designed from the ground up (literally) to be near instant.  That involves point-of-use heaters right at the faucet or shower head - indeed British "electric showers" do this.  Now, flow restrictors make sense - reducing flow reduces the amount of electricity needed at every faucet, and that is the pinch-point issue with tankless - it really takes a lot of electricity! As much as 40 amps per GPM of hot flow.
I have largely given up on tankless because of the electricity requirement. But there's a saving grace, at least for showers.  Drain water heat recovery pre-heating the water input to the tankless.  This greatly reduces the power needed and makes it more practical to fit in an electrical service.  The shower starts with water sitting in the pipe at 70 degrees F, and by the time truly cold water arrives from the street, the drain water heat recovery is working.

How would heat recovery pre-heat the pipes though?  From other water use?

@rogerdpack  Please reread the last three sentences of the post.  It's not using pre-heat in the sense of "before you start the water flowing".  It's using it in the sense of "before you put the water in the point-of-use heater".  Thus why initially it relies on ambient temperature (70 F) preheating the water.  Once it's flowing and the incoming water is ground temperature (e.g. 50 F), it preheats that from the drain water.

OK so drain heat recovery in this case is to allow for a smaller water heater, not a fast startup? It will start at the same temperature, with or without, with, if no recent drain use? :)

@rogerdpack the first pint of water coming through the heat recovery system will be pre-heated by the use of the prior user.  "That was over an hour ago, surely the water will have cooled off!"  Of course.  But look where that water is sitting.   Not outdoors.  Inside the building's insulation envelope, so it will have cooled off to 70F, not 40-50F.   So that means the tankless has a head start, even on the first pint of water.  So you can get away with a smaller heater, and that means you don't have the heinous costs of provisioning big electrical.


I moved into a new construction home 5 years ago with a tankless water heater.

Can I have a tank fed water heater in line with a tankless water heater?

... purchased new house...when looking through I was shown a tankless water heater. Red flag immediately

nothing new, tankless heaters are often problematic and they only work well in the narrowest of scenarios.  "Any ideas?" - troubleshoot the existing model using a nearby faucet where flow distance is less than 5 seconds and observe the time delay due to the tankless kicking on.  Come to grips with reality, rip it out, put in a conventional tank.  There's a reason why conventional water heater tanks are still around and everyone doesn't simply install tankless.  Just because it's new construction (just like some new boeing planes) doesn't mean the house was designed well, the builder simply figures tankless heaters are popular and are the in thing so they choose it.  Your gripe is nothing new, and will only get worse as the tankless ages.

"like some new Boeing planes" - that analogy doesn't work here. That might be if you replaced traditional tank water heater with heat pump - still a tank, similar capacity, still electricity, but different mechanism for heating with advantages (energy) and disadvantages (recharge rate). This is more like replacing a 737 Classic with a fleet of Sikorsky helicopters.

Also conventional work a little better in "hard water" areas I've heard...scale build up is less of an issue I guess? :)

This answer makes no sense. Switching to a tanked heater will not change the fact that it takes time to flush cold water out of long hot-water pipes. Swapping would just be a big waste of money on parts and labor (once) and energy (forever).

i believe my boeing analogy is on point and your helicopter analogy doesn't work.  as for answer not making sense haha you obviously can't read/comprehend my observe time delay due to tankless kicking on nor the numerous complaints you can also find online about this issue not to mention the words from someone here complaining about it ~5 years ago.

I suppose with the global warming conditioning over the last X years it's a hard pill to swallow finding out not everything sold lately as more efficient and  better for the environment than traditional methods isn't always true.

for typical daily hot water residential needs a modern properly installed hot water tank is not outperformed in terms of efficiency due to standby losses versus a tankless.  Unless you simply believe convenience and water waste is not a factor.  Not unlike getting an electric car thinking I'm not using fossil fuel and purposely neglecting to acknowledge how the majority of electricity is produced.

@ron A tankless water heater gets up to temperature in seconds typically.  The difference in wasted water and time should be minimal.  "There's a reason why conventional water heater tanks are still around and everyone doesn't simply install tankless" A big reason is just system design.  You need gas or a large electric feed for the tankless, so it's much harder to replace a tank with tankless depending on your circumstances.  It makes way more sense if you know you're using tankless before the build starts.

key words there: typically and should be minimal yet here we are

and did you just validate my boeing analogy by stating a big reason is system design ?

@ron Your answer also talks about generic tankless installations as if they are all bad, that's why I mentioned how they typically operate.  And no, it doesnt really validate the Boeing analogy.   Boeing has issues with new designs because of corner cutting.  Tankless is popular in new designs because it isn't practical to retrofit, but is practical when you can put the right utilities in place while everything is accessible and still being installed.

@jmac - I specifically said they are often problematic and only work well in the narrowest of scenarios..  how you interpret that to mean they are all bad is on you.  The reality is builders get whatever hot chit advertised tankless and install it in a new house not understanding (or caring?) about those details it's all ooh future tech, save the environment...  and going back to my analogy not unlike the maxx with all its sensors and software to make things better and that automation flies two of them into the ground.
